# If early exercise is a bad idea, why American option is more expensive than European

Tags: options, option-exercise, premiums

American options are more expensive than European options because they give the buyer the right to early exercise.

But in a low interest environment, early exercise is [a bad idea, for most retail traders at least.](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/exercising-an-american-call-option-early)

So it seems like the extra premium paid for American option is not worth it. Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few situations in which it may be advantageous to exercise early. Wikipedia actually has a good explanation:

[Option Style, Difference in value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_style#Difference_in_value)

> To account for the American's higher value there must be some
> situations in which it is optimal to exercise the American option
> before the expiration date. This can arise in several ways, such as:
>
> An in the money (ITM) call option on a stock is often exercised just
> before the stock pays a dividend that would lower its value by more
> than the option's remaining time value.
>
> A put option will usually be
> exercised early if the underlying asset files for bankruptcy.[3]
>
> A deep ITM currency option (FX option) where the strike currency has a
> lower interest rate than the currency to be received will often be
> exercised early because the time value sacrificed is less valuable
> than the expected depreciation of the received currency against the
> strike.
>
> An American bond option on the dirty price of a bond (such as
> some convertible bonds) may be exercised immediately if ITM and a
> coupon is due.
>
> A put option on gold will be exercised early when deep
> ITM, because gold tends to hold its value whereas the currency used as
> the strike is often expected to lose value through inflation if the
> holder waits until final maturity to exercise the option (they will
> almost certainly exercise a contract deep ITM, minimizing its time
> value).[citation needed]